# How to insert a custom task in gradle

Tags: gradle, dependencies, build.gradle

How to define a custom task in gradle, and declare it's dependencies?

In Android Studio project I need to inject a custom task between **processDebugManifest** and **processDebugResources**.

This tasks are part of `gradle assemble` command.

> ~ gradle assemble
>
> :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>
> :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>
> :app:checkDebugManifest
>
> .......
>
> **:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE**
>
> **:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE**
>
> :app:packageRelease UP-TO-DATE
>
> :app:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
>
> :app:assemble UP-TO-DATE
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>
> Total time: 7.628 secs

Answer (score 1):

You can see details in [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html), section **17.4. Adding dependencies to a task**.

Here is an example from documentation, defining custom task, and adding it as a dependency to existing one.

```
task taskY << {
    println 'taskY'
}

taskX.dependsOn taskY
```

Comment: Maybe I I don't have described the problem clearly.I got the answer as following

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all help.

Maybe I I don't have described the problem clearly.

But for android stdio project,you will write a file - 'build.gradle'

And this file will include a plugin - 'com.android.application'

I want to know that I would like to write a task,and this task is adding as a dependency to the existing one in the plugin.

But,I got my answer in a book.

You can see the following example.

```
  android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.install) {
        tasks.create(name: "run${variant.name.capitalize()}", 
        dependsOn: variant.install) {
           description "Installs  and runs the main launcher activity."
   }
}
```